# firebase functions - cannot GET "/"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm currently working on a server-side rendering application, using the Firebase Cloud Functions solution

in order to achieve that, I want to plug at the root url an express instance (for custom routing)

instead of the `/<project>/<zone>/<function>` (ex: `/test/us-central1/helloWorld`) url, I wanted to rewrite it with a simple `/<function>` (`/helloWordl`)

to achieve that I tried unsing the url rewrite Firebase Hosting's feature :

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      { 
        "source": "**",
        "function": "helloWorld"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but now, when I run `firebase serve`, my local server display a 404 error on every url I'm trying

Comment: Do you have a helloWorld function implemented to handle the requests?

Comment: yes that was the default commented route (when you set up the functions with fireabse-tools)

Comment: Please, See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54096387/4516797 Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

uses shown in the official doc "[Customize Hosting Behavior](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites)" are exemples of **redirection to files**, specified with the property key "**destination**"

but when you try to rewrite url **to functions**, use the **function** key instead

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      { 
        "source": "**",
        "function": "helloWorld"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```